# NuGet reference works in dev, fails in production

Tags: visual-studio, json.net, nuget-package, pushsharp

I am using PushSharp to deliver mobile push messages, it is dependent on Newtonsoft.Json.dll.  I have installed Newtonsoft.Json.dll through NuGet as well because I use it for other things too.  A few days ago I updated the Newtonsoft.Json.dll to v 6.x through NuGet in VS2012.  When I run the project in VS2012 there are no problems, however when I deploy to production, PushSharp throws an exception that Newtonsoft.Json.dll 4.5.x cannot be found.  The Newtonsoft.Json.dll requirements for PushSharp according to NuGet Manager in VS2012 is ">= 4.5.x".  Why would it work on my development machine without issue?  I cant seem to find any reference (GAC or bin) Newtonsoft.Json.dll 4.5 anywhere on my dev PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to add an assembly binding redirect to your configuration file:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thank you.  The NuGet/VS update incorrectly updated that section of my config and I completely missed it.